# REST API for filtering

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest

My below code is not working for filtering values based on user name

```
 function onGetUserNameSuccess() {
    var username = user.get_title();
    alert(username);
    var executor;

    executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
    executor.executeAsync({
        url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('LateLogin')/items?$select=Author/Title&$expand=Author&$filter=Author/Title eq '"+username+"'?@target='" + hostweburl + "'",

        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        success: getListItemsSuccessHandler,
        error: getListItemsErrorHandler
    });
}
```

But it goes to error function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('LateLogin')/items?$select=Author/Title&$expand=Author&$filter=Author/Title eq '"+username+"'?@target='" + hostweburl + "'"
```

You are passing user's login name in ther but filtering by `Title`. So modify your url and try

```
/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('LateLogin')/items?$select=Author/Title&$expand=Author&$filter=Author/Name eq '"+username+"'&@target='" + hostweburl + "'"
```

`Author/Title` `eq` `"some value"` means you are filtering by user's display name

`Author/Name` `eq` `"some value"` means you are filtering by user's login name

And it should be `&` instead of `?` before target.

Main part of the query `URL` must be ended up by `?`. Then other parts will be joined by `&`

Comment: in browser m getting data with title but not with Name..also pls tell me if there is any error with the syntax.thanks..

Comment: username means login name or display name

Comment: display name... /_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('LateLogin')/items?$select=Author/Title&$expand=Author&$filter=Author/Name eq 'Vikash Kumar'?@target='" + hostweburl + "'"     this also doesnt work

Comment: in browser it works but in code it does not..\

Comment: it should be & instead of ? before target.